# SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'offsetWidth':

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am getting this error in ie9 and have been pulling my hair out. Basically the "map-canvas" div will not load.

This is the full error I am getting:

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'offsetWidth': object is null or undefined 
main.js, line 29 character 1104

Any help would be appreciated!!

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-maps-mini" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">

<!-- Starts the HTML header area -->
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />

<title>Google Map Demo</title> 

 <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
 </script>

 <script type="text/javascript"> 

    var tableid1 = 4338356;         //Fusion Table ID
    var mylatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.66685, -124.91038); //map centre - Courtenay/Comox  

        function initialize() {

            var myOptions = { 
                            scaleControl: true,   
                            overviewMapControl: true,
                            mapTypeControl: true,    
                            mapTypeControlOptions: {      
                                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DEFAULT    
                                },  
                             zoom: 14,
                             center: mylatlng,       
                             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN    
                            }; 

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions);                        

            var layer1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
                query: {
                        select: "'geometry'",
                        from: tableid1
                        },
                map: map
            });
        };

        function changeMapl() {
            var searchString = document.getElementById('search-string-l').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
            layerl.setOptions({
                query: {
                        select: "'geometry'",
                        from: tableid1,
                        where: "'Name' = '" + searchString + "'"
                        }
            });
        };

     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize());

 </script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Comox Valley Walking Trails</h1>
        <hr />
    </div><!-- end #header -->

    <div id="content-secondary">

        <h3>sidebar1 Content</h3>

        <h4>Trails</h4>

            <select id="search-string-l" onChange="changeMapl(this.value);">
                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                <option value="MacDonald Wood Park">MacDonald Wood Park</option>
                <option value="Goose Spit">Goose Spit</option>
                <option value="Mack Laing Park">Mack Laing Park</option>
                <option value="Filberg Rd to Goose Spit">Filberg Rd to Goose Spit</option>
            </select>

          <div class="clear"></div>

    </div>


    <div id="content-primary"><div id="map-canvas"></div></div>    

    <!-- This clearing element should immediately follow the #mainContent div in order to force the #container div to contain all child floats -->
    <br class="clearfloat" />

    <div id="footer">
    <p>Footer</p>
<!-- end #footer --></div>
<!-- end #container --></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The same issue I m also getting.

Answer (score 0):

This is the error I get in IE8:

Webpage error details

Message: 'null' is null or not an object
Line: 29
Char: 1104
Code: 0
URI: http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/9/7a/main.js

You have several issues:

1. google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize());
   is not correct, you need to change it to 
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
   the way you have it (with the parenthesis) it executes before the map div is defined, resulting in the error above).
2. in ChangeMap1 layerl (layer followed by a lower case "L") is not the same as layer1 (layer followed by the number one).
3. In the code you posted the map-canvas div doesn't have a size (that may not be true for *your* version)

[link to working version](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_GoogleMapDemoA.html)